# IBM MobileFirst Platform Event Source Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Let say user A subscribe event source push notification at device A at 10am and subscribe event source push at device B at 11am without unsubscribe. If my backend send the push message, both devices will receive the push message? I actually just want to send the message to the latest devices user have subscribed. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Idan suggested you can inspect push subscriptions in the database . Susbscriptions have an associated timestamp entry . With this you can determine the latest one for the user.

You can then use [WL.Server.notifyDevice(userSubscription, device, options)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#notifyDevice) or [WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription(deviceSubscription, notificationOptions)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#notifyDeviceSubscription) to target a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

If the user subscribed to two different event sources then yes, the user will receive notifications in both event sources...

There is no built-in mechanism that will prevent "duplicate" subscriptions (of the same user), so perhaps you could implement some sort of a cron job on your server to inspect the subscriptions table in the database and check that there are no duplicate subscriptions. If a duplicate subscription is found, delete the older one.